# Can I develop two rolls of different brand of B&W film together?

Tags: film, black-and-white, developing

Assume they have the same development time.

Is it okay?

Answer (score 4):

Given the fact that they can be developed with the same type of developer and they require the exact same development time, it doesn't really matter the brand of the film.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking if it is OK to assume they have the same development time, then it is not.

This may be a useful guide to [developing times](http://www.digitaltruth.com/devchart.php) for different film and developer combinations.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with Ilford, Kodak and Fuji films. Most of them - but not all - have about the same dev times. The data sheets will tell, otherwise > [digitaltruth.com/devchart-php]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I shoot my last film long time ago, but if films require different kind of process/chemicals I will not risk to develop them together.

And I am sure you are not so short in time and/or chemicals, so just thread them separately :)

At the end all this is about the quality, not the speed (most of the time)